# Фотография в PyQT 5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Надо вставить картинку в PyQt, и чтоб по нажатию клавиш она переворачивалась.

В принципе, понимаю как реализовать переворот, по нажатию клавиш, но как саму картинку вставить - не понимаю.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] , покажите что у вас есть.

Comment: да ладно, реализацию клавиш я сам смогу сделать, мне просто нужно в диалоговом окне чтоб появилась фотка

Comment: ну ладно, сейчас нарисую, но в следующий раз обязательно минимальный пример!

Comment: понял, спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


class myApplication(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myApplication, self).__init__(parent)

        self.rotation = 0

        self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("im.png")

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setMinimumSize(400, 400)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

        button = QPushButton("Rotate 15 degrees")
        button.clicked.connect(self.rotate_pixmap)

        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(button, 1, 0)

    def rotate_pixmap(self):
        pixmap = self.pixmap.copy()
        self.rotation += 15
        transform = QtGui.QTransform().rotate(self.rotation)
        pixmap = pixmap.transformed(transform, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication([])

    w = myApplication()  
    w.show()    

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]